# How do I view the contents of a PFX file on Windows?

Tags: windows, security, certificate, client-certificate

I have a PFX certificate file on my machine and I'd like to view the details before importing it. (The import utility doesn't actually tell you what the certificate is!).

How do I view the details about the PFX certificate file?

Comment: It is 2019 and we still can't easily view a certificate before installing it. We have to go out on the web to find an answer. Sad state of affairs for Microsoft.

Answer (score 259, accepted):

Some options to view PFX file details:

- Open a command prompt and type: `certutil -dump <path to cert>`
- Install OpenSSL and use the commands to view the details, such as: `openssl pkcs12 -info -in <path to cert>`

Comment: The first option is good, but is there any way of seeing more details of the certificate such as the SAN, without installing a third party tool?

Comment: certutil **-v** -dump <path to cert> will display a verbose listing including SAN.

Comment: I have an encrypted pfx file.  Is there any information I can find out about it without knowing the password?

Comment: @mwfearnley, except of recovering the password via brute-force method, I am afraid there is no other option left.

Comment: `certutil -p <cert password> -dump <path to cert>`

Answer (score 13):

You can pipe the info to the openssl x509 utility and then export that out to a file like this:

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -info -in c:\temp\cert.pfx | openssl.exe x509 -noout -text > c:\temp\cert.pfx.details.txt
```

You will be prompted for the certificate passwords too of course.

Answer (score 11):

The contents of a pfx file can be viewed in the GUI by right-clicking the PFX file and selecting **Open** (instead of the default action, Install).

[image: Explorer context menu]

This will open mmc and show the pfx file as a folder.  Open the pfx folder and the Certificates subfolder, and you will see the certificate(s) contained in the pfx.  The certificate can be opened to view details.

[image: example UI]

Alternatively, the GUI can be opened by running `mmc certmgr.msc /CERTMGR:FILENAME="C:\path\to\pfx"`

It is also possible to use [FileTypesMan](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) to change the default (double-click) action for PFX files from Install to Open.

Comment: Unfortunately Explorer's "Open" command in the context-menu just gives me this message: "This file has password protected certificates for the following: Personal Information Exchange." and doesn't let me continue. It never prompts me for a password either.

Comment: This works in Windows 11, but you can't use the `Open` in the first menu, you have to `Show More Options`, then `Open` from there.  (Note: I tested with a .p12 that didn't have a password.)

Comment: Yeah, certmgr can only display pfx files that have no password protection.  If your pfx has a password, you'll need to [remove the password from the file](https://serverfault.com/q/515833) using openssl (or similar) before you can use the GUI to view it.  Of course, if you have openssl, you can just use it to directly display the details on the command line (`openssl pkcs12 -info -in FILE.pfx`).

Answer (score 4):

I know this old but, but I have written a small application that is able to show certificates in PFX files. It doesn't show whether it has key or not, but you can browse through certificates in it.

You can download latest version from the Release section.
Works on Windows and Linux

https://github.com/nomailme/certificate-info
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a python tool that can do this as well. The source is on Github at https://github.com/JavaScriptDude/print_cert .

This tool can print local certificates and PKCS stores or certs on remote sites.

```
usage: print_cert [-h] [--p12 P12] [--cert CERT] [--privkey PRIVKEY]
                  [--host HOST] [--port PORT]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --p12 P12, -p P12     Path to PKCS12/PFX archive
  --cert CERT, -c CERT  Path to certificate pem
  --privkey PRIVKEY, -k PRIVKEY
                        Path to private key pem
  --host HOST, -H HOST  Host Address
  --port PORT, -P PORT  Host Port (default is 443)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: using [SigCheck utility](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck), as mentioned in [Microsoft's Clickonce docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-manually-deploying-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019) (the docs mention examining a .manifest file, but it works on a .pfx file as well).

Outputs looks like:

[image]

Comment: As I understand, sigcheck checks the signature of the specified file(s). Since, pfx file is not signed, the output shows as 'unsigned'. So this way doesn't work there.

Comment: @Jury: is not the question about being able to **view** the contents of the certificate ? This way does show. The file being signed or not is not relevant for the problem posed - as far as I understand.

Comment: Using sigcheck on a pfx adds no useful information that's not also present if you rightclick on the file in explorer and choose 'Properties'