# What's the quickest way on a Windows machine to look at the detail of a p12 certificate?

Tags: certificate

Given a P12 certificate file on Windows, what's the quickest way to see the details such as common name?

Say i have a file `mycertificate.p12`, ideally I'm looking for a command line tool that I can run against the file to show me the details and doesn't require anything extra to be installed.

It looks like openssl has something similar:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -info -noout
```

Comment: Are you talking about an installed certificate, or a certificate file you have yet to install?

Comment: A file. I've clarified the question.

Comment: Try opening a new command window and entering **certutil -dump <certificate full path>**

Comment: I would use OpenSSL

Comment: There is a question here which seems to be the same as I think the process is the same as for a PFX file: http://superuser.com/questions/580697/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-pfx-file-on-windows

Comment: Portecle is also very useful for that: http://portecle.sourceforge.net/ (requires Java installed on your PC)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I view the contents of a PFX file on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/580697/how-do-i-view-the-contents-of-a-pfx-file-on-windows)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think the simplest way is probably this:

- Open a new command window
- Type  `certutil -dump <certificate full path>`

The certutil tool is built in to Windows so you don't need anything to be installed.

Edit:

As  Iain mentioned, since the file can contain a private key you may be prompted for a password. It's possible to specify the password when you run the command, which would have the advantage of allowing you to use command redirection to send the output directly to a text file:

e.g.

`certutil -p MyPassword -dump D:\MyCertificate.p12 > D:\CertDetails.txt`

Comment: Thanks James. I'd say it's worth keeping my question (even with it's -1) given someone searching google might use p12 instead of pfx as a search term.

Comment: Note that certutil will prompt you for the password for the file.

Comment: That's a good point, I will edit the answer.

Comment: Is there a GUI tool instead of a command line one?

Comment: you can also add "-v" before -dump to see more verbose details like signature algorithms, etc.